# Hibernate Batch processing for child table rows

Tags: java, mysql, spring, hibernate, rest

I tried the solution for batch insert in this link [Hibernate Batch insert](https://vladmihalcea.com/how-to-batch-insert-and-update-statements-with-hibernate/), but still not working the way it should. Below is the relevant code for your reference. 
I am uploading just one trial balance file which consists of 100 trial balance rows. So one trial balance is a list of 100 trial balance rows and I need to batch insert these 100 rows of data.
This is a REST API and am using JSON managed reference since its a bi-directional relationship.

The result of below code is 6 rows in trial balance table are inserted, whereas the trial balance row table has 100 rows inserted only for the last trial balance id created, for the remaining id's no data was inserted in trial balance row table.

Can you point out where am I going wrong?

```
***TRIAL_BALANCE Entity***

@Entity
@Table(name="TRIAL_BALANCE")
public class TrialBalance {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
@Column(name="ID")
private int id;

@OneToMany(mappedBy="trialBalance", fetch=FetchType.EAGER, cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
@JsonManagedReference
private List<TrialBalanceRow> trialBalanceRows;

public void addTrialBalanceRows(List<TrialBalanceRow> tbRows) {

if ( trialBalanceRows == null ) {
trialBalanceRows = new ArrayList<TrialBalanceRow>();
}
for ( TrialBalanceRow tb : tbRows ) {
trialBalanceRows.add(tb);
tb.setTrialBalance(this);
}
}

***TRIAL_BALANCE_ROW Entity***

@Entity
@Table(name="TRIAL_BALANCE_ROW")
public class TrialBalanceRow {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
@Column(name="ID")
private int id;

@JsonBackReference
@ManyToOne(fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumn(name="TRIAL_BALANCE_ID")
private TrialBalance trialBalance;

***TrialBalanceDOAImpl.java file***

public void addTrialBalance(TrialBalance trialBalance) {
    try {

        Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();
        Transaction tx = session.beginTransaction();
        for ( int i=0; i<1200; i++ ) {

        session.save(trialBalance);
        if( i % 50 == 0 ) { // Same as the JDBC batch size
              //flush a batch of inserts and release memory:
              session.flush();
              session.clear();
           }
        }
        tx.commit();
        session.close();

    } catch (HibernateException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        throw new DataNotSavedException();
    }
}
```

***hibernate properties***

```
hibernate.dialect = org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect
hibernate.show_sql = true
hibernate.format_sql = false
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.jdbc.time_zone = UTC
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.jdbc.batch_size = 50
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.order_inserts=true
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.order_updates=true
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.jdbc.batch_versioned_data=true
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.id.new_generator_mappings = false
```

***Hibernate Config***

```
private Properties hibernateProperties() {
    Properties properties = new Properties();
    properties.put("hibernate.dialect", environment.getRequiredProperty("hibernate.dialect"));
    properties.put("hibernate.show_sql", environment.getRequiredProperty("hibernate.show_sql"));
    properties.put("hibernate.format_sql", environment.getRequiredProperty("hibernate.format_sql"));
    properties.put("hibernate.jdbc.time_zone", 
            environment.getRequiredProperty("spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.jdbc.time_zone"));
    properties.put("hibernate.jdbc.batch_size", 
            environment.getRequiredProperty("spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.jdbc.batch_size"));
    properties.put("hibernate.order_inserts", 
            environment.getRequiredProperty("spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.order_inserts"));
    properties.put("hibernate.order_updates", 
            environment.getRequiredProperty("spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.order_updates"));
    properties.put("hibernate.jdbc.batch_versioned_data", 
            environment.getRequiredProperty("spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.jdbc.batch_versioned_data"));
    properties.put("hibernate.id.new_generator_mappings", 
            environment.getRequiredProperty("spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.id.new_generator_mappings"));

    return properties;
```

}

***Logs***

> 2018-07-12 16:28:25 TRACE AbstractEntityPersister:3142 - Updating entity: [in.greenstack.ikon.entity.TrialBalanceRow#107399]
>   2018-07-12 16:28:25 DEBUG AbstractBatchImpl:129 - Reusing batch statement
>   2018-07-12 16:28:25 DEBUG SQL:92 - update TRIAL_BALANCE_ROW set ACCOUNT_CODE=?, ACCOUNT_NAME=?, CLOSING_BALANCE=?, GL_AMOUNT_CURR=?, GL_AMOUNT_PROP=?, GL_AMOUNT_REV=?, OPENING_BALANCE=?, REMARKS=?, TRANSACTION_CR=?, TRANSACTION_DR=?, TRIAL_BALANCE_ID=? where ID=?
>   Hibernate: update TRIAL_BALANCE_ROW set ACCOUNT_CODE=?, ACCOUNT_NAME=?, CLOSING_BALANCE=?, GL_AMOUNT_CURR=?, GL_AMOUNT_PROP=?, GL_AMOUNT_REV=?, OPENING_BALANCE=?, REMARKS=?, TRANSACTION_CR=?, TRANSACTION_DR=?, TRIAL_BALANCE_ID=? where ID=?
>   2018-07-12 16:28:25 TRACE AbstractEntityPersister:2723 - Dehydrating entity: [in.greenstack.ikon.entity.TrialBalanceRow#107399]
>   2018-07-12 16:28:25 TRACE BasicBinder:65 - binding parameter [1](https://vladmihalcea.com/how-to-batch-insert-and-update-statements-with-hibernate/) as [INTEGER] - [0]
>   2018-07-12 16:28:25 TRACE BasicBinder:65 - binding parameter [2] as [VARCHAR] - [POOJA ENTERPRISE]
>   2018-07-12 16:28:25 TRACE BasicBinder:65 - binding parameter [3] as [DOUBLE] - [0.0]
>   2018-07-12 16:28:25 TRACE BasicBinder:53 - binding parameter [4] as [DOUBLE] - [null]
>   2018-07-12 16:28:25 TRACE BasicBinder:53 - binding parameter [5] as [DOUBLE] - [null]
>   2018-07-12 16:28:25 TRACE BasicBinder:53 - binding parameter [6] as [DOUBLE] - [null]
>   2018-07-12 16:28:25 TRACE BasicBinder:65 - binding parameter [7] as [DOUBLE] - [0.0]
>   2018-07-12 16:28:25 TRACE BasicBinder:53 - binding parameter [8] as [VARCHAR] - [null]
>   2018-07-12 16:28:25 TRACE BasicBinder:65 - binding parameter [9] as [DOUBLE] - [14000.0]
>   2018-07-12 16:28:25 TRACE BasicBinder:65 - binding parameter [10] as [DOUBLE] - [14000.0]
>   2018-07-12 16:28:25 TRACE BasicBinder:65 - binding parameter [11] as [INTEGER] - [361]
>   2018-07-12 16:28:25 TRACE BasicBinder:65 - binding parameter [12] as [INTEGER] - [107399]
>   2018-07-12 16:28:25 TRACE AbstractEntityPersister:3142 - Updating entity: [in.greenstack.ikon.entity.TrialBalanceRow#107400]
>   2018-07-12 16:28:25 DEBUG AbstractBatchImpl:129 - Reusing batch statement
>   2018-07-12 16:28:25 DEBUG SQL:92 - update TRIAL_BALANCE_ROW set ACCOUNT_CODE=?, ACCOUNT_NAME=?, CLOSING_BALANCE=?, GL_AMOUNT_CURR=?, GL_AMOUNT_PROP=?, GL_AMOUNT_REV=?, OPENING_BALANCE=?, REMARKS=?, TRANSACTION_CR=?, TRANSACTION_DR=?, TRIAL_BALANCE_ID=? where ID=?
>   Hibernate: update TRIAL_BALANCE_ROW set ACCOUNT_CODE=?, ACCOUNT_NAME=?, CLOSING_BALANCE=?, GL_AMOUNT_CURR=?, GL_AMOUNT_PROP=?, GL_AMOUNT_REV=?, OPENING_BALANCE=?, REMARKS=?, TRANSACTION_CR=?, TRANSACTION_DR=?, TRIAL_BALANCE_ID=? where ID=?
>   2018-07-12 16:28:25 TRACE AbstractEntityPersister:2723 - Dehydrating entity: [in.greenstack.ikon.entity.TrialBalanceRow#107400]
>   2018-07-12 16:28:25 TRACE BasicBinder:65 - binding parameter [1](https://vladmihalcea.com/how-to-batch-insert-and-update-statements-with-hibernate/) as [INTEGER] - [0]
>   2018-07-12 16:28:25 TRACE BasicBinder:65 - binding parameter [2] as [VARCHAR] - [Poonam Pride Bunglows]
>   2018-07-12 16:28:25 TRACE BasicBinder:65 - binding parameter [3] as [DOUBLE] - [0.0]
>   2018-07-12 16:28:25 TRACE BasicBinder:53 - binding parameter [4] as [DOUBLE] - [null]
>   2018-07-12 16:28:25 TRACE BasicBinder:53 - binding parameter [5] as [DOUBLE] - [null]
>   2018-07-12 16:28:25 TRACE BasicBinder:53 - binding parameter [6] as [DOUBLE] - [null]
>   2018-07-12 16:28:25 TRACE BasicBinder:65 - binding parameter [7] as [DOUBLE] - [3842.0]
>   2018-07-12 16:28:25 TRACE BasicBinder:53 - binding parameter [8] as [VARCHAR] - [null]
>   2018-07-12 16:28:25 TRACE BasicBinder:65 - binding parameter [9] as [DOUBLE] - [15467.0]
>   2018-07-12 16:28:25 TRACE BasicBinder:65 - binding parameter [10] as [DOUBLE] - [11625.0]
>   2018-07-12 16:28:25 TRACE BasicBinder:65 - binding parameter [11] as [INTEGER] - [361]
>   2018-07-12 16:28:25 TRACE BasicBinder:65 - binding parameter [12] as [INTEGER] - [107400]
>   2018-07-12 16:28:25 DEBUG BatchingBatch:384 - Executing batch size: 50

I am using Hibernate v5.2.17 with spring security and spring v5+.

Thanks,
Bhavna

Answer (score 1):

The best way to figure out what happens is to [enable JDBC logging](https://vladmihalcea.com/the-best-way-to-log-jdbc-statements/).

In your case, it's not clear whether you are committing the transaction. Are you using `@Transactional` on your service?

Also, you should use a proper logging framework, not `e.printStackTrace`.

Comment: Yes I am using @Transactional on the service

Comment: Then, use logging and see what statements are executed.

Comment: I now see batch inserts being done, but its quiet slow for around 1200 rows of data. Is there something else I am missing. Have updated the post with few logs and config changes that worked.

Comment: I see another issue, that the parent table has multiple inserts of same row. So in above example if the addTrialBalance() method in DAO has the for() loop for 15 rows of data with batch size of 5, I see 4 rows added in TrialBalance (parent) table and the TrialBalanceRows (child) table has data entered only for the last parent id generated. Why 4 inserts in parent table are generated?

Comment: It's all explained in that resource that I gave you. Just read it and you'll understand how INSERT batch ordering works.

Comment: I understand the concepts you have explained in the book, but I feel the issue here is not with performance, but with the way I am inserting the data. In all the batch insert examples both parent and child have similar number of rows of data insertion. In my example, the parent table will always have just one row of data whereas the batch insertion is required more for child table insertions. How can I use hibernate for OneToMany mapping with first only parent getting saved and then perform batch insertion on child rows?

Comment: Well, if you read that chapter carefully, you'll learn about the "order_inserts" configuration property that does exactly what you want. You want to say that you read the entire chapter and didn't stumble on that part about "order_inserts"?

Answer (score 0):

Just for anyone else who would need to refer in future, the solution that worked for me was writing own SQL queries for batch inserts as below. Also I removed the CASCADETYPE.ALL feature in parent entity.

```
@Override
    public void addTrialBalance(TrialBalance trialBalance) {
        try {

            //Batch insertion code
            Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();
            Transaction tx = session.beginTransaction();
            final int batchSize = 50;


            session.save(trialBalance);
            session.doWork(new Work()
            {
                public void execute(Connection con) throws SQLException
                {
                    PreparedStatement st = con.prepareStatement(""
                            + "insert into TRIAL_BALANCE_ROW (ACCOUNT_CODE, ACCOUNT_NAME, ....,TRIAL_BALANCE_ID) "
                            + "values (?, ?,...,?)");
                    List<TrialBalanceRow> tbRows = trialBalance.getTrialBalanceRows();
                    List<TrialBalanceRow> trialBalanceRows = new ArrayList<TrialBalanceRow>();
                    int count = 0;

                    for (TrialBalanceRow tb : tbRows)
                    {
                        trialBalanceRows.add(tb);
                        tb.setTrialBalance(trialBalance);

                        count++;
                        st.setString(1, tb.getAccountCode());
                        st.setString(2, tb.getAccountName());
                        st.setDouble(3, tb.getClosingBalance());
                        .
                        .
                        .
                        st.setInt(11, tb.getTrialBalance().getId());
                        System.out.println("Adding to batch .......");
                        st.addBatch();

                        if(count % batchSize == 0) {
                            System.out.println("Executing Batch Size of : " + batchSize);
                            st.executeBatch();
                        }
                    }
                    st.executeBatch();
                    st.close();
                }

            });

            session.refresh(trialBalance);
            tx.commit();
            session.close();


        } catch (HibernateException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            throw new DataNotSavedException();
        }
    }
```

Thanks Vlad for your references (especially the one on GENERATIONTYPE.AUTO) and all the help, but even with order_inserts I was not able to get the desired result. With above solution I am able to achieve the required performance.